# Trying to match email address and error message in non-delivery report

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to write a csharp app which parses NDRs (non-delivery reports) sent when an email is un-deliverable. The goal is to unsubscribe email addresses from our mailing lists which are no longer valid.

I've managed to write code which connects to our exchange server using the exchange web services API (EWS). Grabs the message body and what I want to do is match the email address and error code so that we can generate a report of email addresses and errors for manual review.

The content of the body of a message appears as such:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p><b><font color="#000066" size="3" face="Arial">Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:</font></b></p>
    <font color="#000000" size="2" face="Tahoma">
    <p><a href="mailto:email@domain.com">email@domain.com</a><br>
    A communication failure occurred during the delivery of this message. Please try resending the message later. If the problem continues, contact your helpdesk.<br>
    </p>
    </font><br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <font color="#808080" size="2" face="Tahoma">
    <p><b>Diagnostic information for administrators:</b></p>
    <p>Generating server: WEB16.domain.net</p>
    <p>email@domain.com<br>
    #&lt; #5.5.0 smtp;554 Sending address not accepted due to spam filter&gt; #SMTP#</p>
    <p>Original message headers:</p>
    <pre>Received: from WEB12 ([192.168.33.64]) by WEB16.domain.net with Microsoft
     SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);    Sun, 8 Jul 2012 09:27:42 -0400
    Thread-Topic: domain.com order 178014 has been received and is pending
    thread-index: Ac1dDXyHxyN&#43;loq8SeaIzTsVoLE/3g==
    From: &lt;sender@domain.com&gt;
    To: &lt;recipient@domain.com&gt;
    CC:
    BCC:
    Subject: domain.com order 178014 has been received and is pending
    Date: Sun, 8 Jul 2012 09:27:56 -0400
    Message-ID: &lt;22C1C2F24E1744D4B51C1A5EF9DE3E50@domain.net&gt;
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    X-Mailer: Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000
    Content-Class: urn:content-classes:message
    Importance: normal
    Priority: normal
    X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V6.1.7601.17609
    Return-Path: sender@domain.com
    X-OriginalArrivalTime: 08 Jul 2012 13:27:42.0955 (UTC) FILETIME=[743A53B0:01CD5D0D]
    </pre>
    </font>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that will match the email address that was sent to, and the accompanying error message.

```
            // First we set the input string.
            string body = message.Body.Text;

            // Regex string
            Regex emailregex = new Regex("^<p>(.+?)</a><br>$");

            var match = emailregex.Match(body);

            if (match.Success)
                 Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);

            // Regex string
            Regex errorregex = new Regex("</a><br>\n(.+?)<br>$");

            match = errorregex.Match(body);

            if (match.Success)
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

Neither of the regular expressions I setup appear to not be working. I'm not much of a regular expression guru. Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Brad

Comment: I've gotten a bit closer. With Regex errorregex = new Regex("#&lt;(.+?)&gt;"); That now matches the error returned. However I'm still not having luck matching the email address.

Comment: Hmm I managed to use the following to match the email address: Regex emailregex = new Regex("To: &lt;(.+?)&gt;"); This seems to work although I am not sure if its the most elegant. I am still testing. If anyone has suggestions for a more elegant/reliable way to do this I'd welcome them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complicated task because various email relay software generates very different email formats, requiring you to eventually grow a complex set of error email templates and simple (but probably different code wise) matching algorithms.  Even worse, new templates will keep appearing and you will have to keep updating your parser.  Do not expect a simple regex match to handle all this.

Your last regex

```
"To: &lt;(.+?)&gt;")
```

looks good for the task, but only with this particular returned email template.  In other cases it can be as bad as detecting other email addresses (from messages that have been replied to).

I suggest that you switch to a mailing list manager that can handle unsubscribes automatically, as opposed to programming this piece yourself.

If this is not an option for you, you will have to add blocks of code that check for particular known templates recognized with reasonable certainty, as opposed to just extracting the failing address from the template.

Comment: Messages are sent using our own inhouse IIS SMTP servers and appear to be semi-consistent. I've managed to mostly get this working except that there appears to be two error messages reported. One in the NDR and another in an attachment. Sometimes the two don't jive and so I am trying to grab them both. I've got the second one but the first I can't seem to match

Comment: What I am trying to match is:  <p><a href="mailto:email@domain.com">email@domain.com</a><br>
    A communication failure occurred during the delivery of this message. Please try resending the message later. If the problem continues, contact your helpdesk.<br>
    </p> I am ussing the following regex to do so: new Regex("</a><br>\r\n(.+?)<br>\r\n</p>");

Comment: If it's all from one server, that's no problem.  However, the data you show does not match (question and comment; regex and comment).  Your question has `^<p>(.+?)</a><br>$`, which would work correctly against the sample message in the question).  Important: construct the `Regex` object like this:  `new Regex("^<p>(.+?)</a><br>$", RegexOptions.Multiline)`.  If you don't use this option, `^` and `$` will want to match the whole message, not just one line of it.

Comment: The regex you suggested in the previous comment doesn't seem to be working. I would also think it would be matching more than just the error. I would think it might match the email address and the error. I tried to tweak the regex as follows but its just not working. Any suggestions? Regex errorregex2 = new Regex(@"</a><br>(.+?)<br></p>$",RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

Comment: @Brad - Technically it was you who suggested it in the question, I am just saying (and have verified) that the group matches the address in the HTML you sent.  So I suspect that you might be testing something else than you have pasted into the question.  "Not working" is too broad, try to describe what you are trying and seeing without any ambiguity or generalization.  Ideally edit the original question to make it clear which line of your code does something else than you expected, and double check all details you provide.